# pip install vs python -m pip install

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if there are any **diference** between these two commands:

`$ python -m pip install Django`

Found in **Django** oficial documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/install/#database-installation

and this:

`$ pip install Django`

Which I found in the https://pypi.org/project/Django/ (Python official repository)

Both to be typed in a **virtual environment** created previously:

`$ python3 -m venv venv`

Thank you.